# Find text between list of keywords and point with RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex, keyword

```
# coding=utf-8
import re

m = "Hola esto es un ejemplo Objeto: esta es una de, las palabras."

keywords = ['Objeto:', 'OBJETO', 'Objeto social:', 'Objetos']

obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\b\s*(.*?),'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))))
print obj.findall(m)
```

I want to print text between one of words of keywords and the next point. Output that I want in these case: "esta es una de, las palabras."

Comment: Since your keywords are a list of multi-word entries, even space-separated, and they overlap, you should consider building the alternation by first sorting the items by lengh in descending order, as I showed [here](https://ideone.com/bxJJ5C). Otherwise, you may get unwanted text in the result.

Comment: Oh perfect. This solution is much more optimal than mine. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, I am not still sure about word boundaries though. Probably you will need to really discard the right-hand side boundary as Jean-Francois uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the trailing `\b` prevents the match because your keyword ends with `:`

simplify your regex by removing it. Plus the greedy / comma `(.*?),` is only extracting the first part before comma, I suppose you meant "to the next point": `(.*?)\.`

```
obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\s*(.*?)\.'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))))
```

result:

```
['esta es una de, las palabras']
```

Removing the word boundary can match part of keywords in sentences though. You could *force* a non-word char with `\W` afterwards and it would work (acting like word boundary):

```
obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\W\s*(.*?)\.'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))))
```

Comment: Expected output includes `, las palabras.`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but want the whole sentence to the point. Like: esta es una de, las palabras

Comment: yes, I want that my output to be ['esta es una de, las palabras']

Comment: @AnnaCastan try changing the Regex code to `\b(?:{})\s*(.*?)\.`

Comment: @marco_gorelli Exacly!! Thank you so much to everybody :) :)

Comment: too quick. This was an easy fix _if you care enough_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b(?:{0})\s*(.*?)(?=\b(?:{0})|$)` with lookahead instead:

```
import re
m = "Hola esto es un ejemplo Objeto: esta es una de, las palabras."
keywords = ['Objeto:', 'OBJETO', 'Objeto social:', 'Objetos']
obj = re.compile(r'\b(?:{0})\s*(.*?)(?=\b(?:{0})|$)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))))
print(obj.findall(m))
```

This outputs:

```
['esta es una de, las palabras.']
```

Comment: Also this answer works so good!! Thank you so much @blhsing :)